# How to succesfully run an export task using Google Earth Engine in NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, google-earth-engine

Im trying to create a simple NodeJS app to export a tile/map using Google Earth Engine library. I have create and run the code. The code using a GeoJSON Geometry as an input which will be converted to ee.Geometry to create grid map using coveringGrid method. This covering grid will be then exported to a tile/map for visualization.

If I am using the same code in Google Earth Engine Code Editor, it will run smoothly but If I run it in NodeJS, the operation state will always be pending. How to fix that?

I have attached the NodeJS script as GitHub Repo and GEE Code Editor script to do that with different result. I also attach the GeoJSON data. I also will share you the result of the success one.

GEE Code editor script (succes): https://code.earthengine.google.com/15cdaf02cb9e841404dd22b927075ac1
Expected final result: [https://storage.googleapis.com/fa-rs-bucket/tile/grid/tile_grid_1694672053/{z}/{x}/{y}](https://storage.googleapis.com/fa-rs-bucket/tile/grid/tile_grid_1694672053/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D)

NodeJS script (failed): https://github.com/ramiqcom/grid
Link on checking the task operation: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0957afeb512fa1ece6a6d94fcd085609 (change the operation name based on the NodeJS console.log)

Unfortunately there is limited documentation on exporting GEE data in NodeJS. I can only find it in either the repo or stackoverflow.
So I follow a guy script, and it successfully run the Export but the state of the Export is still pending.
I was hoping that the exported task will exist in GEE Code Editor Task, but it doenst so I use `ee.data.getOperations`. Still whenever I check the task, it still in Pending state.